# XcodeのKey Bindings設定がうまくいかない

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6, os-x-key-bindings

Key Bindings内の、「Move Focus To Next Area」のキーを変えようと思っているのですが、
デフォルトの「cmd + alt + `」から変えても、
「Move Focus To Next Area」と「Move Focus To Previous Area」でキーバインドが被っていると怒られてしまいます。
変えようにも選択出来ないのでどうしたら良いか分からず困っています。
宜しくお願い致します。

以下環境
MacOSX 10.9.5
Xcode 6.2
JISキーボード
入力ソース ことえり、U.S.

Answer (score 1):

いったん `Move Focus To Next Area` の行を選択した状態で `delete` キーを押して既定の割り当てに戻してから、再び Key を変更すると、上手くいくかもしれません。

[image: Move Focus To Next Area の行を選択]

通常 `Move Focus To Next Area` に設定した Key に Shift が加えられたものが `Move Focus To Previous Area` の Key に自動で割り当てられるようなのですけど、具体的な再現方法まではわかりませんが、何かの拍子で両方に同じ Key が割り当てられてしまう様子です。

いったん既定の設定にリセットしてあげると、同じキーが設定されてしまう状況もいったんリセットされる様子でした。

Comment: 種類によっては、両方に同じKeyが割当てられてしまうみたいですね。
試行錯誤してみます。

Answer (score 0):

もし好みのキーバインドを割り当てることが最優先なら OS X の `システム環境設定` から `キーボード` の `ショートカット` を設定する方法もあります。

左枠で `アプリケーション` を選択して、そこに "Xcode" を対象にして `Navigate->Move Focus To Next Area` や `Navigate->Move Focus To Previous Area` にキーを割り当てると、そのキーを使って操作できるようになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]